# Deferred locking system for guaranteed ordering

Tags: java, locking

Does Java have a built-in locking mechanism where one "takes a number" (establishes a future locking order), does some work, and later blocks until "now serving" reads our ticket number?

Here is a pseudo-code overview of what I mean:

```
public CompletionStage<Void> onEvent()
{
  return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
  {
    // Establish future locking order without acquiring a lock
    int ticket = takeTicket();
    // Execute network request asynchronously
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> networkRequest(), threadPool).
      thenCompose(() ->
      {
        // Trying acquiring a lock. If the locking system is
        // waiting for someone with a smaller number, block
        // until our turn comes up.
        lock(ticket);
        // ... do work that depends on strict event ordering ...
        return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() ->
        {
          fireMoreEvents();
          // Permanently discard the lock, allowing the next user to lock.
          release(ticket);
        }, eventDispatcher);
      });
  }, eventDispatcher);
}
```

- Ticket numbers must be processed in sequential order.
- If users are waiting to lock and the user holding the current ticket does not lock and unlock within `timeout` milliseconds, throw an exception (to indicate that there is some sort of programming error on my part).
- Attempting to reuse an expired ticket (one that was already used, or timed out) throws an exception

If this isn't built into Java, is there a good way to implement this without waking up all blocked threads every time the number being served is incremented?

### Rationale for locking mechanism

I have an event listener that must record events in the order that they are received, but it must record related information from an asynchronous source (e.g. the network) alongside the data.

Comment: Yup. Can do this with a [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Can you please post an answer with sample code? I see the parallels in terminology, with the current phase number representing "now serving" but I fail to see how one can grab "the next number" at registration time. `register()` tells me the current phase number and  `getRegisteredParties()` tells me how much to add to it, but the latter is not thread-safe. I understand that once I have my registration number, I can use `awaitAdvance(int phase)` to wait on it to be called. Do I just lock on something while retrieving `getRegisteredParties()` or is there a better way?

Comment: @BoristheSpider It's also not clear how to force the lock to advance to the next number if no one claims it within `timeout` miliseconds.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, do you require the strict event ordering to be somehow strictly happens-before the next task the thread does? It strikes me that pusing the stictly ordered events onto a `BlockingQueue` and having something else process them would give the order. Push a `CompletableFuture` onto the queue in `takeTicket` and resolve it in the `lockTicket` - this would release the processing thread. The processing thread can `get(timeout)` to deal with the advacement. Would that work? Simpler than battling with `Phaser`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I've updated the question to clarify that I want to shift control from thread A to B, then back to A while maintaining the same ordering both times that A is running. The problem with your solution (as I understand it) is that you expect `takeTicket` to be passed a `CompletableFuture` for the second execution of `A`. But the second execution of `A` depends on information generated by `B`. So I can't construct a `CompletableFuture` the first time `A` runs. This means that I cannot push a `CompletableFuture` onto the queue at that point. Also, post a formal answer. Thank you.